# Konica Bizhub Photocopier - Change Pin

Tags: password, password-management

We have a Konica Bizhub Photocopier. When we use the device, we have to enter the pin/password: 1135. I also have to use this pin when I authenticate a user account so they can print over the network.

How can I change this log in pin?

The admin password is different.

Answer (score 1):

Every bizhub has an admin menu and unfortunately, KM makes it hard to find. You can change that pin in this admin menu or even remove it, but you have to login with an admin account on the machine.

Comment: Would you mind outlining the steps because I have been spending hours on this. I click <Utility - Administrator settings> but then I can find how to change this sign in password.

Comment: One other thing I thought of, this might be stored within the driver, too. I know that KM has a specific driver that requests a pin when you print. If you check the advanced settings in the driver, do you see the option to put a pin in there?